# Gekko ARX model crash possible to load last iteration

Tags: python-3.x, crash, load, gekko, mpc

I am pretty new to model predictive controls modeling with Gekko and in general.

I have created an ARX MPC in Gekko, which is working great. I, however, noticed that in the first 50-80 iterations, the results are well.. disappointing. However, after the first iterations, I get good results (I guess the ARX algorithm is at play here or possible BIAS?). Now my problem is that the model might crash after some time, and I have to redo the 50-80 iteration to get good results again, is there a way to "save" the last calculated model and use that when rebooting the calculations?

Comment: Could you post example code and data of the issue that you are observing? It is hard to give specific advice without a reproducible application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are likely encountering is that the "prior" values have not yet been initialized. Try solving once with a steady-state initialization as shown in the [example MPC application with the TCLab](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabF?action=sourceblock&num=4) that is the final source block on for [TCLab F](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabF).

```py
m.options.IMODE=1
m.solve()
```

You can then switch to control or simulation mode:

```py
# set up MPC
m.options.IMODE   = 6 # MPC
m.time=np.linspace(0,120,61)
```

**Background information on using ARX models**

Identification of the ARX model and prediction or control with the ARX model are two separate applications.

**Identify ARX Model**

[image: ARX Model Identification]

The `m.sysid()` function to identify an ARX model does not save an archive but does return the model as output arguments:

```py
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,pred='meas')
```

The model is returned as `p`.

```py
# see https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/ARXTimeSeries
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data and parse into columns
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/tclab_dyn_data2.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
t = data['Time']
u = data['H1']
y = data['T1']

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# system identification
na = 2 # output coefficients
nb = 2 # input coefficients
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,pred='meas')

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u,label=r'$Heater_1$')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Heater')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp)
plt.legend([r'$T_{meas}$',r'$T_{pred}$'])
plt.ylabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.show()
```

**Predict with ARX Model**

[image: Predict with ARX model]

Below is an example of prediction with the ARX model.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

na = 2 # Number of A coefficients
nb = 1 # Number of B coefficients
ny = 2 # Number of outputs
nu = 2 # Number of inputs

# A (na x ny)
A = np.array([[0.36788,0.36788],\
              [0.223,-0.136]]) 
# B (ny x (nb x nu))
B1 = np.array([0.63212,0.18964]).T
B2 = np.array([0.31606,1.26420]).T
B = np.array([[B1],[B2]])

C = np.array([0,0])

# create parameter dictionary
# parameter dictionary p['a'], p['b'], p['c']
# a (coefficients for a polynomial, na x ny)
# b (coefficients for b polynomial, ny x (nb x nu))
# c (coefficients for output bias, ny)
p = {'a':A,'b':B,'c':C}

# Create GEKKO model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

# Build GEKKO ARX model
y,u = m.arx(p)

# load inputs
tf = 20 # final time
u1 = np.zeros(tf+1)
u2 = u1.copy()
u1[5:] = 3.0
u2[10:] = 5.0
u[0].value = u1
u[1].value = u2

# customize names
mv1 = u[0]
mv2 = u[1]
cv1 = y[0]
cv2 = y[1]

# options
m.time = np.linspace(0,tf,tf+1)
m.options.imode = 4
m.options.nodes = 2

# simulate
m.solve()

m.open_folder()

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(m.time,mv1.value,'r-',label=r'$MV_1$')
plt.plot(m.time,mv2.value,'b--',label=r'$MV_2$')
plt.ylabel('MV')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(m.time,cv1.value,'r:',label=r'$CV_1$')
plt.plot(m.time,cv2.value,'b.-',label=r'$CV_2$')
plt.ylabel('CV')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

The model is saved in the `m.path` folder that can be viewed with `m.open_folder()`. Set `m = GEKKO(remote=False)` to calculate locally and observe all of the files that are used to generate the model and the solution.